# searching through a varying array in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

There is an array `nodes[]` which is updated over several iterations. So in each iteration of the loop, its size will increase. In every iteration i have to go through each element of the `nodes[]`. I want to do this without keeping track of the current size of array. I am sure there is a Matlab way to process through all elements of `nodes[]` without maintaining a counter that is increased by one every time an element is added into the `nodes[]`. How to do that? Note it is not important that in every iteration one element will be added to the `nodes[]` and also not more than one element can be added per iteration. I have done something like this:

```
counter=sizeof(nodes)

loop{
update nodes[]
if element added
    counter=counter+1

for (i=1;i<=counter;i++)
    process nodes[i]
}
```

Comment: Not very clear on the question, but see if this helps upon replacing the `for-statement` : `for i = 1:numel(nodes)`.

Comment: It counts all elements of `nodes[]`. But every entry of `nodes[]` is an array of length 2, so `numel(nodes)/2` does the work for me. Is there a more general way?

Comment: If you mean `counting the number of elements`, `numel` is the preferred and general way to express that.

Comment: If nodes is a two-dimensional array, `size(nodes, 1)` might do the trick. But your whole code does not seem very Matlaby (disregarding the syntax). It might help if you explain what you are actually trying to do to get a good answer.